# open URL with IF THEN

Tags: java, android

I would like to open a website with IF THEN command in my app.

Here is my code thus far:

```
if (RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS.equals ("google")){
        Executions.getCurrent().sendRedirect("http://www.google.com", "_blank");
```

but it says 'executions' can not be resolved.

Than kyou in advance.
Flinx

Comment: import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

Comment: if (RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS.equals(url)){
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.mkyong.com"));
    startActivity(intent);
  }

Comment: What class is that android.executions ? Eclipse w/ADK does not provide class import option which if available will normally do... ??